# Difference between the num as char and as int on memory - Regarding the equivalent num on the ascii -

Tags: c++, char, integer, ascii, integer-promotion

What's the Difference between the number as char and the number as int (or any type, which I can make any arithmetic operation using it like double on c++) on memory - Regarding the equivalent number on the ascii code -.
Also, how ('5'-'0') can help me to convert a char into int?
what's the mechanism of that?

Comment: All numbers are the same in C++. As far as how `'5'-'0'` works, that's basic math? Like, subtraction? That's the mechanism?

Comment: The character `'0'` has a non-zero numeric value (i.e. `int('0') != 0`) and the arabic numerals (`'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, .... `'9'`) are a contiguous set (i.e. `'1' - '0' == 1`, `'2' - '0' == 2`, ... `'9' - '0' == 9`) in all standardised character sets (and in the C++ standard). This can be exploited by code converting strings to their numeric values (e.g. `"123"` to `123`).

Answer (score 2):

In this declaration

```
int num = 5;
```

the integer variable `num` contains the value `5`.

In this declaration

```
char num = '5';
```

the character variable `num` contains the internal representation of the character literal `'5'` that is in ASCII is equal to `53` or `0x35` in hex.

In the source and execution basic character sets the characters `'0' - '9'` are stored sequentially without gups. So for example `'5' - '0'` that is the same in ASCII as `53 - 48` yields the integer value `5`.

From the C++ Standard

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
> each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
> one greater than the value of the previous

Objects of the type `char` used in expressions are usually promoted to the type `int` that is called integer promotions.

The type `char` can behave as the type `signed char` or `unsigned char` depending on compiler options.